# Connect-PnPOnline : The term 'Connect-PnPOnline' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, cmd, sharepoint-online

I have windows 7 64-bit , and i have install sharepoint management shell from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588.

but when i open the SP management shell and i try to run this command:-

```
PS C:\> Connect-PnPOnline https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/***/
```

I got this error:-

> Connect-PnPOnline : The term 'Connect-PnPOnline' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-PnPOnline 
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-PnPOnline:String) [], C    ommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

so not sure what i am missing?

Here is my version table:-

```
PS C:\> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.22198
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: Have you ran the [install-module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) ?

Comment: @jrider trying to run this command will raise this error `Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1`

Comment: After further reading of the documentation (initial comment) there is an alternate installation for lower versions of powershell. However, it does mention you major version (`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`) should be above 3 (You might need to update). In short, it says you can run this to install the module: `Invoke-Expression (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sharepoint/PnP-PowerShell/master/Samples/Modules.Install/Install-SharePointPnPPowerShell.ps1')`

Comment: @jrider this will try to install a software named package managemnt.. i am not sure if i should trust this

Comment: This documentation is from Microsoft (I would trust it). If you don't feel comfortable with it. Your only other alternative is to update your PowerShell version.

Comment: @jrider now i run the above script as you mentioned `Invoke-Expression (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sharepoint/PnP-PowerShell/master/Samples/Modules.Install/Install-SharePointPnPPowerShell.ps1')` then i restarted my PC,, but when i try to run `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` .. i got the following error `Install-Module : The 'Install-Module' command was found in the module
'PowerShellGet', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run
'Import-Module PowerShellGet'.
At line:1 char:1`

Comment: . now i am running sharepoint online so is the script you mentioned targetting it ?

Comment: `Install-Module` does not work in your version of powershell. Try running your `Connect-PnpOnline` again

Comment: @jrider also `$PSVersionTable` is showing the same values .. should this got updated after the installation link you send?

Comment: @jrider i am getting this now `Connect-PnPOnline : The term 'Connect-PnPOnline' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.`

Comment: This did not update powershell. This is just a way to get the module installed (per the documentation). Check to see if you have the module installed by running `Get-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell* -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name,Version | Sort-Object Version -Descending`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169959/discussion-between-jrider-and-john-g).

Comment: I'm moving this to chat. It is getting rather extensive

Answer (score 4):

Please install the Pnp PowerShell assembly in your system from here:

[SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

And then consume in SharePoint Online Management Shell:
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com –Credentials (Get-Credential)

It will pop up a credential window, input credential and then continue:
[image]

Comment: Seem to be seeing this type of problem:  https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1340  "Connect-PnPOnline : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Scopes'"

Answer (score 2):

If the machine has Internet access and you're on PowerShell 6 or later, it's actually easier to use PowerShell-Get by running:

```
Install-Module SharepointPNPPowershellOnline
```

Note: PowerShellGet is available for earlier PowerShell versions as well, but needs to be installed first - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/installing-psget).