# jenkins agent started by a task scheduler: powershell command is not recognized

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins

- I have an agent, windows server 2019, for my Jenkins.
- I have a task scheduler that starts the agent. by executing "javaws http://jenkins/computer/agentName/slave-agent.jnlp"
- I have a Jenkins job, with a step "Windows PowerShell", contains a command "Connect-PnPOnline"

The problem:
I get the error "Get-PnPFile : The term 'Get-PnPFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

However, when I start the agent by manually (instead of by executing the task) "javaws http://jenkins/computer/agentName/slave-agent.jnlp", then it works correctly

Comment: Apparently the PowerPoint module is not installed under the Jenkins agent: `Install-Module SharepointPNPPowershellOnline`. See also: [Connect-PnPOnline : The term 'Connect-PnPOnline' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50065007/1701026)

Comment: Install the module under the same privilege's as the job runs. As admin the module should be in programfiles or windows dir, as user in your user dir. Checkout Get-Module -ListAvailable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Jenkins agent searched in "C:\Users\myUser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
I copied PnP.PowerShell from C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

I understood the problem by looking in $ENV:PSModulePath